# Why is my swf taking up more space than it actually is?

Tags: html, css, resize, flash, overflow

I created a simple flash animation to work like a slideshow on the front page of my website. Because the container was 640 by 500 with a padding of 10 px all around, I made the swf 620 by 480 to fit perfectly. For some strange reason, whenever I preview my site or upload it to my host server, scroll bars appear, indicating that the animation is slightly too big. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Here's the HTML pertaining to the animation and the container:

```
<div class="mainspace">

<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="620" height="480" id="windexslideshow">
<param name="movie" value="images/indexslideshow.swf"/>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="images/indexslideshow.swf" width="620" height="480">
    <param name="movie" value="images/indexslideshow.swf"/>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
<!--<![endif]-->
    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/></a>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object> 
</div>
```

And here's the CSS for the container:

```
.mainspace {
width:620px;
height:480px;
overflow:auto;
position:absolute;
text-align:left;
margin:0px 0px 0px 160px;
padding:10px; /*adds to the content area above (width and height), so it's actually 640 by 500*/
z-index:1;
}

.mainspace img {
border:none;
}

.mainspace .slide {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:620px;
}

.imglinks1 {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:50px;
border:none;
z-index:2;
}

.imglinks2 {
margin:0 0px 0 0px;
float:left;
border:none;
z-index:3;
}

body .mainspace {
}

.mainspace p {margin:0px 0 14px 0;}

.mainspace h1 {margin-left:10px; font-size:18px; color:#56AD3D; clear:both;}
.mainspace h2 {margin-left:10px; font-size:15px; color:#56AD3D; clear:both;}
.mainspace h3 {margin-left:30px; font-size:15px; color:#56AD3D;}
.mainspace h4 {margin-left:40px; font-size:15px; color:#56AD3D;}
.mainspace h5 {font-size:16px;}
.mainspace h6 {font-size:16px;}

.mainspace a:link {color:#E0D3C6; text-decoration:none;}
.mainspace a:visited {color:#56AD3D; text-decoration:none;}
.mainspace a:hover {color:#56AD3D; text-decoration:none;}*/
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<div class="mainspace">` Is actually 620x480 (not 640x500, as you said), with a padding of 10px. This makes the actual area of the `<div>` 600x460, since padding is on the inside, so you are overflowing.

Change

```
.mainspace {
  width:620px;
  height:480px;
  ...
```

to

```
.mainspace {
  width:640px;
  height:500px;
  ...
```

Comment: That's really odd. I always thought that padding subtracted from the total area of a div. I tried what you suggested and it worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: It does, that's exactly the point. Padding is on the inside of the element, margin is on the outside. So what you had done by creating an element the same size as your swf and padding it by 10px on every side is make an area 20px too small for your swf. On a side note, instead of the `margin: 0px 0px 0px 160px;` you could just do `margin-right: 160px;`...

Comment: The margin on the left is for a side menu. The mainspace div is stacked inside the container div, next to the side menu. I actually created the swf after the CSS and scaled it to fit within the padding in the mainspace div.

Comment: Because of the padding, the correct size to scale the swf to fit in your original CSS would be 600x460 ;-)

Comment: Why so low, when the padding's only 10 on each side?

Comment: Because your orginal size was 620x480, and you need to take the container padding off that. Since the padding is 10px on all sides, you take 2x10 off each dimension, =600x460. To be honest I get the impression you know all of this and you have been working on this particular problem for so long that you can't see for looking. Go make yourself a cup of tea and come back to it and I bet you'll be kicking yourself - you sound like you actually know what your doing.

Comment: The original size is 640 by 500. And then with the padding, it's 620 by 480. That's why I'm wondering if it's something within the embed code for the swf.

Comment: When you say 'the orginal size' what *exactly* are you refering to? The original dimensions of the swf when it was created? Lets put it this way - how big do you *want* the swf to be and how big do you *want* the container to be?

Comment: I tell you what might be simpler, is to give the swf object a `margin: 10px;` and remove the width, height and padding from the container. This should produce the same result (since the position of the container is `absolute`) but it will mean that all sizing and spacing will be relative to the swf iteslf, and all you need to do to change it is adjust the width and height of the swf.

Comment: All this is probably because I neglected to post the entirety of my CSS here. Long story short, the container for the whole site is 800x600. Within the container is lmenu, which is 160px wide, and mainspace, which is 620x480. The bottom 300 px is unimportant. With a padding of 10px on each side, the mainspace div becomes 620x480. My swf is 640x480, so it should fit right within the mainspace, right? Nope. That's the problem. Now, is part of the embed code, namely the "object classid" part, unnecessary? Because, according to Firebug, it's adding a small empty object to the bottom of my div.

Comment: If your swf is actually 640x480, you can just take the padding off the left and right and it should all fit together exactly. regarding the extra `<object>`, I was wondering about that myself and (although I can't say I know this for definite) I believe that objects like that with a classid are only required (for flash) to make it work on IE<7. It's certainly a Windows-specific thing because it refers to a UUID.

Answer (score 0):

The DIV with the class mainspace has a left margin of 160px; is that what you mean?

Comment: Nope, the margin is there because, as a whole, the space of the site is 800x600px. There's another div on the left of the mainspace div. It's something about the mainspace div's padding and the swf that's the problem.